# Restricting characters in bootstrap input field using pattern attribute

Tags: html, validation, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following field in bootstrap framework php page.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="inp_field1" id="inp_field1" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Do it here..." value='<?php echo($data_text_1)?>' required 
                                data-toggle="tooltip" title="Do it here..." tabindex="3">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to restrict few characters say for example /@. How can I restrict specific characters. Not looking for what can be allowed but what cannot be instead. Ideally if it can be done using pattern attribute, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="inp_field1" id="inp_field1" 
             class="form-control input-sm" 
             placeholder="Do it here..." value='<?php echo($data_text_1)?>' 
             required data-toggle="tooltip" title="Do it here..."   
             tabindex="3"
             pattern="[^@\\]">
</div>
```

Comment: it was giving highlighting(red box) for characters including alphabets. Normally highlighting happens when a restricted character is entered

Comment: Is html5 ... is not spefic for a  browser .. then should work